# Remove past dates and next months dates from the current month

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to remove the past dates and next month's dates from the fullcalendar? So for the current month it should display only current dates and days.

Comment: I doubt that there is an option for this. But you can download the source code and make a custom build.

Answer (score 14):

You could try skipping the events in the eventRender() method:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view)
{
   if(event.start.getMonth() !== view.start.getMonth()) { return false; }
}
```

Comment: for version 2.0 or higher you need to add "._d" 

event.start._d.getMonth()
view.start._d.getMonth()

Comment: Well, when I applied "event.start._d.getMonth() !== monthView.start._d.getMonth()" for month view, all my events are gone.

Comment: For version 2.0 or higher, it's not working. Can someone share a solution?

Comment: Hey y'all. I have a working answer below that works with modern versions of FullCalendar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32847680/1174795

Answer (score 12):

Add this setting `showNonCurrentDates: false`. With this setting, dates and events that do not belong to the current month will not be shown.

```
$('#calendarId').fullCalendar({
     // Other settings
     showNonCurrentDates: false            
});
```

Answer (score 9):

The grid cells for the next and previous month have the class "fc-other-month", so you can target them that way:

e.g.:
The hide the day numbers,
add the CSS:

```
.fc-other-month .fc-day-number { display:none;}
```

or run this JavaScript:

```
$(".fc-other-month .fc-day-number").hide()
```

Comment: This a) wouldn't hide the events on those dates and b) would only work on dates from the past month, but not on those dates in the past that are in the current month.

Comment: So cant we hide the past dates in the current month's view??

Comment: The best way to alter events in the past would be to patch fullcalendar.js so that it adds a class to events that end before today's date. I'd add an if statement to the part in fullCalendar that iterates around the events and builds the markup (around line 4646 in v1.5.1)

Here's the code I'd use:
`if (event.end < new Date())
{
   classes.push("fc-event-past")
}`

You can then use that class to select the elements in jQuery or CSS and style them differently or call .hide() if you want.

Comment: @DavidWebster To apply the patch, where would that be in v2.5.0?

Answer (score 6):

Try this!

```
$('.fc-other-month').html('');
```

This works for me!

Comment: Thank you...short and simple

Comment: Done in viewRender callback. Works!

Answer (score 5):

None of the solutions provided on this answer properly solve the problem with the current version of FullCalendar. Using Bascht's answer as a starting point, I've updated his approach to use the current FullCalendar APIs. Below is working example code that will accomplish this task:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var eventDate = event.start;
    var calendarDate = $('#activitiesCalendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
    if (eventDate.get('month') !== calendarDate.get('month')) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that whatever the id is of your calendar should be used in the jQuery selector for fetching the calendarDate object on the 3rd line of my example code.

Comment: This should be the correct answer - Thanks for posting this!

Comment: Yes, this worked for me also. This should be the answer. Thanks Zetta.

Answer (score 2):

For Full calendar v5.0, add the below line in full calendar js:

```
showNonCurrentDates: false
```

Add below css to your page:

```
.fc-day-disabled {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    var currentMon = new Date(event.start);
    var currentMonth = currentMon.getMonth();

    var currentMonViewStart = new Date(view.start);
    var currentMonthViewStart = currentMon.getMonth();

    var currentMonViewEnd = new Date(view.end);
    var currentMonthViewEnd = currentMonViewEnd.getMonth();

    if((currentMonth == currentMonthViewStart) && (currentMonth  == currentMonthViewEnd)){ 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me to remove previous and next month events from calendar.

Comment: In the above code I compared the event start month with current calendar display month and event start month with the end month of current calendar display. If all same then return false to display. It works amazing.....

Answer (score 1):

for version 2.0 or higher:

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
   if(event.start._d.getMonth() !== $('calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')._d.getMonth()) { 
      return false; 
    }
}

// if you want to remove other month's days from view add to css:
    .fcc-other-month { 
        visibility:hidden;
     }
```

Comment: jettpleyn: for the eventRender, would it go before the event? I am having issues with not displaying the actual events and not the dates

Comment: here is my question with the code I have on the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220785/full-calendar-how-to-distinguish-past-events-and-future-events

Comment: your class name should start from .fc- and not .fcc- but I can't edit your post due to minimum edit length requirement

Answer (score 1):

Try using weekMode: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekMode/.

```
weekMode: 'liquid', or `weekMode: 'variable',`
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Or,

     fixedWeekCount: false

Answer (score 1):

For newer version of FullCalendar plugin, the following works utilizing Moment.js helper functions:

`eventRender: function(event, element, view){
    var evStart = moment(view.intervalStart).subtract(1, 'days');
    var evEnd = moment(view.intervalEnd).subtract(1, 'days');
    if (!event.start.isAfter(evStart) ||
        event.start.isAfter(evEnd)) { return false; }
},`

Answer (score 1):

Using event render and a callback  function solved my issue .Perfectly hiding previous and next month events from current view

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                        if (view.name == "month") {
                            if (event.start._i.split("-")[1] != getMonthFromString(view.title.split(" ")[0])) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

function getMonthFromString(mon) {
            var d = Date.parse(mon + "1, 2016");
            if (!isNaN(d))
                return new Date(d).getMonth() + 1;
            return -1;
        }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you can try this clientOptions `'showNonCurrentDates' => false, and 'fixedWeekCount' => false,`

This code allow me to hide the days of previous months and next months but the cells of thouse days remains:
Try using [Fullcalendar Doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/fixedWeekCount/)

```
<?= $JSCode = <<<EOF
function(event, element, view) {

if(event.nonstandard.status =='0'){
 element.find(".fc-title").css({"color": "red"});   
 $('.fc-day-top[data-date="'+event.nonstandard.date+'"]').find('.fc-day-number').css({"background-color": "red", "color": "white"});                   
} else if(event.nonstandard.status == '1'){
   element.find(".fc-title").css({"color": "#1ab394"});                      
  $('.fc-day-top[data-date="'+event.nonstandard.date+'"]').find('.fc-day-number').css({"background-color": "#1ab394", "color": "white"});                     
}else if(event.nonstandard.status == '4' || event.nonstandard.status == '5'){
   $('.fc-day-top[data-date="'+event.nonstandard.date+'"]').find('.fc-day-number').css({"background-color": "#676a6c", "color": "white"});                                          
}else if(event.nonstandard.status == '3'){
 element.find(".fc-title").css({"color": "red"}); 
 $('.fc-day-top[data-date="'+event.nonstandard.date+'"]').find('.fc-day-number').css({"background-color": "red", "color": "white"});                        
}else if(event.nonstandard.status == '2'){
    element.find(".fc-title").css({"color": "orange"}); 
 $('.fc-day-top[data-date="'+event.nonstandard.date+'"]').find('.fc-day-number').css({"background-color": "orange", "color": "white"});                        
}                           

if(event.nonstandard.working_hours) { 
    var new_description =  '<strong>Total' + '    : </strong>' + event.nonstandard.working_hours + '<br/>';
    element.append(new_description);  
} } EOF;


        yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
            'id' => 'calendar',
            'options' => [
                'lang' => 'en',
                'header' => [
                    'left' => 'prev,next today',
                    'center' => 'title',
                    'right' => 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                ],
            ],
            'clientOptions' => [
                'height' => 750,
                'showNonCurrentDates' => false,
                'language' => 'en',
                'eventLimit' => true,
                'selectable' => true,
                'selectHelper' => true,
                'droppable' => false,
                'editable' => false,
                'fixedWeekCount' => false,
                'defaultDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'eventRender' => new JsExpression($JSCode),
            ],
            'events' => Url::to(['/user/myattr/jsoncalendar'])
        ]);
        ?>
```

[image: full calendar custom view]

Comment: `'showNonCurrentDates' => false, and 'fixedWeekCount' => false,` this does the job. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.fc-other-month').html('');
```

and for disabling other month:

```
$(".fc-other-month").addClass('fc-state-disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Checked below solution in **Full Calendar Version-4**. It works, hides previous and next month's days and also does not pass previous/next month date in events URL.

```
showNonCurrentDates: false
```

Thanks to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version I used:

```
eventRender: function(event,element,view) {
    var view_title = view.title;
    var event_title = event.start;
    var event_title2 = moment(event_title).format('MMMM YYYY');
    if(event_title2 !== view_title) { 
        return false; 
    } else {
        var idname = 'event' + event.id;
        $(element).attr('id', idname).addClass('ttLT').attr('title', event.title);
        var mytitle = event.title;                              
        if (mytitle.toLowerCase().indexOf("open timeslot") >= 0)
        {
            $(element).addClass('alert').addClass('alert-success');
        }
        else{
            $(element).addClass('alert').addClass('alert-info');
            $(element).find('.fc-event-title').addClass('capitalize');
            $(element).find('.fc-event-inner').addClass('capitalize');                                                                                                                              
        }                                               
        element.qtip({
            content: event.description,
            style:{classes:'qtip-bootstrap'},
            position:{my:'bottom right',at:'top left'}
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me on version 3.6.1

```
 eventRender: function(event, element, view)
 {
     if(!event.start.isBetween(view.intervalStart, view.intervalEnd)) { return false; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove past dates and next months dates events from the current month in year view using this trick.

```
eventAfterAllRender: function() {
                            $(".fc-other-month").each(function() {
                                var index=$(this).index();
                                var aa= $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").find("tr").
                                find("td:nth-child("+(index+1)+")");
                                aa.find(".fc-day-grid-event").hide();

                            });
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the text as background color, i.e white so it will be invisible

```
td.fc-other-month {
        color: white;
    }
```

But it your version is >= 3, then you can check parameter- [showNonCurrentDays : false](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/showNonCurrentDates), but this is for month view.

Answer (score 0):

As of **Full Calendar v5.11.0**, `eventRender` is no longer a valid option and the other answers didn't work for me. Using the [VisibleRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange) function is what ended up doing the trick for me.

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialView: 'timeGrid',
  visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
    // Generate a new date for manipulating in the next step
    var startDate = new Date(currentDate.valueOf());
    var endDate = new Date(currentDate.valueOf());

    // Adjust the start & end dates, respectively
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1); // One day in the past
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 2); // Two days into the future

    return { start: startDate, end: endDate };
  }
});
```