# How to hide previous and next month dates and events from yearview of fullcalender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, fullcalendar

[image]I want to hide the previous and next month dates and events from yearview of fullcalender in Asp.Net. Currently I am using the css code which hides the dates but not the date events.

```
td.fc-other-month {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
```

How could I remove the date events as well?

Comment: This might get you on the right track:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1440237.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of those solutions will do?

[Remove past dates and next months dates from the current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628040/remove-past-dates-and-next-months-dates-from-the-current-month)